# Track email form submissions in Adobe Dynamic Tag Management (DTM)

Tags: google-analytics, adobe, universal-analytics, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to track form submissions by creating a data element and rule in Adobe DTM. I'm new to DTM and am having difficulty configuring the tag correctly. Here's a screenshot of my code: http://zeffective.d.pr/1hTHa. How should I create this rule in DTM to track email form submissions as an event in GUA (I've created a tool for GUA in DTM already).

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this (jQuery form submit, etc) but using an event-based rule should work just fine.

Something like this:

```
Event Type: Click

Element Tag or Selector: button.form-submit.disabled-submit // class name
Apply Event Handler Directly to Element

// Adobe Analytics Section

// Select s.tl (does not increment a PV)
// Set events or vars
```

You can also do this with a page rule that uses jQuery and listens for the form.submit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. So here's what I have now: [link](http://zeffective.d.pr/1b22G). Essentially, an event-based rule that is set to fire on a data element that I created ("form-submit"). But I'm still having trouble seeing conversions for this in Google Analytics…do I need the "form-submit" data element condition shown in the screenshot link above? Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the reason for using a data element as a condition? That may cause issues depending on the timing and what that DE needs to return true. I honestly would start by validating your button click first. Once you have validation, push data to GA and AA.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to set it up correctly is:

create event base rule,
chose event type click and check option delay link activation (this will avoid page reload before analytics call is made).

Apply event handler directly to element - leave this option unchecked.

Please do not set any other conditions as mentioned in comments above. 
Choose analytics tool set s.tl and map your evars/props/events

Also, please check _sattelite.getVar("data element name") function to check that Data Elements are resolved properly.

Use browser addons like omnibug to check that calls are made as expected.

In section Javascript / Third Party Tags, for testing purposes you can add following java script:

console.log('new submission');

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have form validation happening I would not use an on click event in DTM. For form submissions, my preferred method is to use the form onsubmit handler and fire a direct call event to DTM after any other logic / validation happens.

```
_satellite.track('lead_form_submit');
```

Set up all your tracking logic in a Direct call rule that has a string to match what you pass to track. ie. 'lead_form_submit' or whatever you name it.

Comment: There are a number of ways to validate a form submission with an event-based rule. The key is understanding how and when the validation occurs (JS vs ajax vs next page, etc.). As you mention, using a DC rule would also work --  as would a page load rule. Just depends on the timing and when the data should be sent.

Comment: Thanks BrettAHale. I'll try this.